# Connecting to libswift-p2p with WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, p2p, webassembly

I'm trying to port a video player Android App to a Web App. The app uses a library called "libSwiftP2P.so".

From looking at the code of the app, all I managed to figure out is that it connects to a STUN server and uses libSwift for Peer-To-Peer connections.

There isn't much information about libSwift online. The only somewhat useful results I found was [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/libswift/libswift), and the [libswift.org](https://libswift.org/) website, neither of which have been updated in the last 5 years.

I understand that there is a high chance that what I am trying to do is near to impossible. Although both technologies utilize P2P, WebRTC and libSwift might be completely incompatible with one another.

Another option I considered was compiling libSwift's C++ code into WebAssembly, and using that to connect.
However, I haven't ever done anything with WASM and it is probably a way more complicated process than I am putting it.

I would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on this, or if you just tell me that it's not possible, and to give up. Thank you.

Comment: i would suggest reading if an precompiled library for some specific platform is what is clever to use with webassembly which is focusing multiple platforms at once.